# MySQL IF function - WHERE 'field1 > 0' ? 'field2 < field1' : ''

Tags: mysql

I need help translating this into a MySQL statement. I need to do something like:

```
WHERE IF 'field1 > 0' THEN 'field2 < field1'
```

Right now, I have this MySQL statement, but doesn't work?:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE IF(field1>0, field2<field1, 1=1) AND field3='1';
```

Please advise a solution for this. Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by your 2nd part after the `THEN`?

Comment: Also, how does `field3` fit in the first statement.

Comment: It's OK... I speak noobese. See my answer for what he means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using logical ANDs and ORs.

```
WHERE (field1 > 0 AND field2 < field1) OR (field1 <= 0 AND <else part of the statement>)
```

The `<else part of the statement>` is the condition that you want to check if `field1` is not `> 0`, unless there is no such a clause, in which case remove the OR and everything after it.

Comment: Doh! I overlooked this lol, regardless, thanks this would do it!

Answer (score 0):

You only want to check `field2 < field1` if `field1 > 0`, so code it that way:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table`
WHERE ((field1 > 0 AND field2 < field1) OR field1 <= 0)
AND field3 = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a case statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` 
WHERE 
  field2< CASE WHEN (field1>0) THEN field1 ELSE field2+1 END 
  AND field3='1';
```